# Azure storage through java MVC web site

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have a java web app using Spring and hibernate framework. I am moving this web app on azure. In on premises web app there is one functionality in which I upload the image first in a temporary folder in C: and later access that file for application. The location of uploaded file is also stored in DB for further references. I have defined the base-path for uploading file in a properties file and accessing through it in controller as well as service layer for creating the directory, file name and file path.

Can any tell me how to do the same in azure using azure storage? Any help is appreciated.

Code in properties file:

```
# Base File Path for Uploading Files 
fileupload.basepath=C:/webApp
```

Code for creating temporary folder

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    // 0. notice, we have used MultipartHttpServletRequest

    // 1. get the files from the request object
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();

    MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());

    if (!CommonUtil.isNull(mpf)) {
        if (mpf.getSize() > ProductCommonConstants.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
            return CommonConstants.STR_FAILURE;
        }

    }

    long fileName = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    final String modelImageDirPath = baseUploadFilePath + "/"
            + CommonConstants.TEMP_FILE_NAME;

    // Check for folder existence
    final File modelImageDir = new File(modelImageDirPath);
    if (!modelImageDir.exists()) {
        // Create the directory
        modelImageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        String contentType = mpf.getContentType();

        if (contentType != null) {

            is = new DataInputStream(mpf.getInputStream());

            // just temporary save file info
            File file = new File(modelImageDirPath + "/" + fileName);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Write to the file
            IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } finally {

        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // Log the Exception

        }
    }

    // 2. send it back to the client as <img> that calls get method
    // we are using getTimeInMillis to avoid server cached image

    return "/service/common/file/get/" + fileName;

}

}
```

Comment: You can still store those files with a relative path instead of a absolute path. But, be ware that, after you redeploy the web app, those files will be overridden. If you want to store those files in the storage, you can read the java API of Azure Storage. Here is the document - [How to use Blob storage from Java](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/) and [How to use File Storage from Java](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage/)

Comment: how to take path of the uploaded blob? I want to store the path of the file in DB.

Comment: You said you need to store the path in DB. That means you don't want your files to be overridden. A blob's path might look like this: `http://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>`. Please read the 2 articles I provided above. You can choose between blob storage and file storage. A blob storage can be served directory through browser which is good for images, while a file storage can be mounted in VMs or cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, you can use the `upload(InputStream sourceStream, long length)` of Class `CloudBlob` to upload files from Spring MVC `MultipartFile` to Azure Blob Storage, please see the code below modified from your code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    // 0. notice, we have used MultipartHttpServletRequest
    // 1. get the files from the request object
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
    if (!CommonUtil.isNull(mpf)) {
        if (mpf.getSize() > ProductCommonConstants.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
            return CommonConstants.STR_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    long fileName = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    // Modified from your code: START
    String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + "AccountName=your_storage_account;" + "AccountKey=your_storage_account_key";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("<blob-container-name>");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        String contentType = mpf.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null) {
            is = new DataInputStream(mpf.getInputStream());
            long length = mpf.getSize();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(""+fileName);
            blob.upload(is, length);
        }
    // Modified from your code: END
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // Log the Exception

        }
    }   
    // 2. send it back to the client as <img> that calls get method
    // we are using getTimeInMillis to avoid server cached image
    return "/service/common/file/get/" + fileName;
}
```

For downloading or referencing the blob, you need to record the container name & blob name of the blob to the database.

```
OutputStream os = ...; // get the OutputStream from the HTTP Response
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("<container-name>");
CloudBlob blob = getBlockBlobReference("<blob-name>");
blob.download(os)
```

For more information, you can refer to the Javadoc of Class `CloudBlob` http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html and the Get started doc for Blob Storage https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/.

Comment: Thanks.. is there any way to upload a buffered image to azure storage?

Comment: @Nidhee In addition to using the Azure Storage SDK for Java, you can directly use the [Azure Storage REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx) in Java. But it's not necessary because of the SDK wrapped these REST APIs.

Comment: @Thanks a lot Peter. As you said above for referencing blob, you need to record container & blob name in DB. But for my on premises web app I'm giving the path to the image and referring it to display as a logo. For Azure web site also I need the same functionality. I tried saving the url to blob in DB and refer it but it's not happening. Can you give any suggestion?

Comment: @Nidhee Try to use the REST API for [`Get Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx), and you can try to use the SDK to get the url via the function [`getUri`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html#getUri()) and generate the SAS taken via the function `generateSharedAccessSignature` for the required request headers.

Comment: Thanks. I referred to your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881757/format-of-private-blob-storage-url-for-get-file-rest-api). It helped but can we make the signature to expire never?

Comment: @Nidhee You can make the expire time enough long.